# Double quotes in DataTable.select filter String

Tags: vb.net

I have to search within a Datatable. the datatable is built by an SQL query. I've got to search for a value in a column, and when I find that value I want back the value of some other cells in the same row. 
And that works. The problem is that my search String is provided from the database too, and sometimes there are some sizes in inches, and the double quotes messes up my search. I know I should escape the double quotes with another double quote, but when i do, the filter returns no row even if the value is right.

I have a list of `KeyValuePair(String, String)`, and a `DataTable` search into

```
For Each variable As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In varset
    Dim temp As New String(String.Format("ShortName ='{0}' AND OldValue='{1}'", variable.Key, variable.Value))
    Dim rows As DataRow() = tab.Select(temp)

    Console.WriteLine(variable.Key + " " + variable.Value)
    If rows.Length = 0 Then
        'returns an error
    Else

    End If
Next
```

When the first query returns the search value, and that is something like "¾” NPT ANSI B 1.20.1", I have to escape it to "¾”" NPT ANSI B 1.20.1", but then the search doesn't work, even if an eventual check tells me the two string are the same (I know I shouldn't trust the debug window about the strings, but it looks like it's the string in the debug that goes into the filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escaping a double quote with another double quote is correct. However, the inch mark you show is not a "normal" ASCII double quote (Unicode \u0022) as it shows a bit more curve or angle on it sort of like how an accent mark isn't the same as an apostrophe. It is either a double prime (Unicode \u2033) or right double quotation marks (Unicode \u201d). If I copy what you wrote into MySQL table it also wouldn't find the record. Once I changed the inch mark to a normal ASCII double quote it would find the record. So 2 obvious options are:

1. sanitize the data in your database to use Unicode \u0022 for inch
   marks.
2. when SELECTing from your database to populate your DataTable, use the appropriate function(s) necessary to replace that character with
   Unicode \u0022.